# VB.NET compiled app setup for x86 platform won't run on Windows XP/Vista 32-bit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, x86, windows-xp, platform

Using VS 2010 Ultimate on my Windows 7 64-bit machine, I wrote a Windows Forms Application with Visual Basic and then compiled it with "Build" command specifically for x86 platforms ( I have tried assigning both "x86" and "Any CPU" on Active solution platform options in Configuration Manager). I have also made sure that TargetPlatform is set to x86 on Project Properties.

However, when I'm trying to run the .exe or the .msi file on my XP 32-bit machine, I get this message:
"This product is designed for x64 platform but is being installed on Intel. Obtain the correct setup from the manufacturer."

.NET Framework 4 client profile, which is a Prerequisite for my application, is also installed on the XP machine.

Does anyone have a clue for this? How can I fix this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For XP, it must be SP3 and XP Pro.  And of course the NET framework has to be installed.

Comment: What kind of Setup framwork are you utilizing?

Comment: @Plutonix it is indeed XP Professional SP3 & NET framework 4.0 is installed

Comment: @MrPaulch I don't understand your question, as I am not an experienced VS user. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Well how do you generate the `.msi`?

Comment: @MrPaulch I have added a setup project to which I have assigned some dependencies: the application .exe, .NET framework & another .exe which is required. Then I'm just "building" the application and after that the setup project

Comment: Have you set the `Active solution platform` to `x86` in the `Configuration Manager` of the installer?

Comment: @MrPaulch yes I have done that for the WindowsApplication project. For the setup, VS doesn't give me any option to choose from.

Comment: Thats why I asked, what kind of Setup up you build. Using the default `Installer` project of VS you have a `Configuration Manager` in the `Properties` section of the Installer project.

Comment: @MrPaulch from File->Add New project->Setup & Deployment->VS Installer->Setup project, that's what I created, but upon clicking on Configuration Manager in the Properties section of the Installer project, there is no active option for platform. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you have no platform to choose from? (then create one) or are you missing the option to select the Platform?

Comment: @MrPaulch I mean I am missing the option to select the Platform.

Comment: What **does** the `Configuration Manager` contain in your release?

Comment: @MrPaulch here is a printscreen of the Configuration Manager http://i1311.photobucket.com/albums/s663/stereotype232323/VS2010_zpsa2811cbb.png

Comment: Ok this is funny, have you checked the final build for architecture? Particulary, whether it really is targeted at AnyCPU|x86. You can use something like CFF Explorer or Reflector.

Comment: @MrPaulch I tried to use Reflector for Application.exe architecture (not sure if this is the correct way), here is a printscreen: http://i1311.photobucket.com/albums/s663/stereotype232323/VS2010_2_zps9ea6549b.png  As you can see, target platform is x86. I even tried messing with the XML configuration and Manifest; changed the "processorArchitecture=MSIL" to x86 but again the setup wouldn't run on XP. Anyway, thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 2010, but in VS2008 it is sometimes necessary to go to Project Properties, Compile, Advanced Compile Options, and change the target CPU to from AnyCPU to x86.